# Serverless Typescript Error : TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Tags: node.js, typescript, frameworks, serverless, serverless-webpack-plugin

[Serverless-Webpack Typescript Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nAjkW.png) "serverless-webpack" error .

Getting Error: Type Error ---------------------------------------------

TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of null

Stack - Serverless backend with Typescript,Node.js and AWS Lambda

Using serverless-webpack package for my current stack,it was working till last day, suddenly it stopped working and getting below error. Tried downgrading version for serverless-webpack but still getting error.

Comment: what is the version of serverless framework you are using?

Comment: My serverless version is 2.57.0

Answer (score 0):

What about node and npm versions? I've had some issues when switching to node.14 and npm.7.
What I've found on the internet, there are some issues with npm.7. If this is your case as well, downgrade npm.